# React.js audio playing with Howler.. play/stop functionality with a button styling difference in case of playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, howler.js

I have this list of tracks and I want to have a "stop play" icon for the button of the song that is currently playing.. and then return it back to a "play" icon when not currently playing the track. The icon change works but the sound instead of stopping.. just starts running all over again on top of the already running sound from before. How to fix?

```
  const [visibleItem, setVisibleItem] = useState(null);

  let sound = null;

  const soundPlay = (src) => {
    if (sound !== null) {
      sound.stop();
      sound.unload();
      sound = null;
    } else {
      sound = new Howl ({
        src,
        html5: true,
        volume: 0.2
      })
      sound.play();
    }
  }

  const select = (i) => {
    if (visibleItem === null) {
      setVisibleItem(i);
    } else {
      setVisibleItem(null);
    }
  }

  const playFunction = (preview, i) => {
    soundPlay(preview);
    select(i);
  }

  const displayTracks = playlistData.map((track, index) => {
    return (
      <tbody key={track.track_id}>
        <tr className="song">
          <td className="play-preview">
            <button className="play-btn" onClick={() => playFunction(track.preview, index)}>
              {visibleItem === index ? <FaStopCircle/> : <FaPlayCircle/>}
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    )
  })
```

So far I have also looked into the option of a simple audio tag with html.. with the default controls.. which does the job perfectly.. but then again.. I don't want all the buttons and progress bar/time stamps that it provides. I would still much rather find a solution to the original problem. Anyone out there got any ideas?